# How ”routing decision“”reroute check“ decide which next-hop to chose in the figure of Netfilter

Tags: netfilter

In Wikipedia of Netfilter article， there is a figure [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg).
the hop of "routing decision" and "reroute check" have multi next-hop, and the next-hops are very similer:
[image]

Who can tell me why and how to choose the next hop, with example is better.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a networking pro, but I did find this email that does shed some light on what re-route check means. Paraphrasing: basically, if you change the fwmark (in any of those filter tables) the fwmark can affect routing decisions, and must be re-checked. Technically, any change of saddr, daddr mark and tos properties cause a re-check. Otherwise, its a no-op.

source: https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg43087.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After my learning about Linux networking，I think the key point is the “bridge device”， it worked on the Link Layer，and used for Virtual machain，Container，tunnel and so on.
[image]
If the Host machain communicate with outer network, Only "Network Layer" route will pass though;

IF the Virtual machain communicate with the outer network, Only "Link Layer" route will pass though;

IF Host machain communicate with the Virtual machains、Containers， it will use the route from Link Layer to "Network Layer" or vice versa.

The "Link Layer" stand for data that will use virtual bridge device.